# Add pre and post event triggers to Pub-Sub pattern

Tags: javascript

I was working with a PubSub implementation and thought it would be nice to have a post event option. While I was at it we might as well tack on a pre too. I wanted the syntax to be something along the lines of

```
events.subscribe.pre(event, callback)
events.subscribe(event, callback)
events.subscribe.post(event, callback)
events.publish(event, args) <-- args are optional
```

I couldn't find much of any information on if it was possible to have 'subscribe()' and 'subscribe.pre()' both be valid options. After quite a while I ended up forcing the issue with a prototype and binding the second layer methods to the prototype.

It works. Is there a better way to do this, possibly as a class, and is it just a bad idea overall?

```
function PubSub() {}

PubSub.prototype = {
    subscribers: {
        pre: {},
        main: {},
        post: {}
    }
}

PubSub.prototype.subscribe = function(event,callback) {
  this.subscribers.main[event] = this.subscribers.main[event] || [];
  this.subscribers.main[event].push(callback);
}

PubSub.prototype.subscribe.pre = function(event,callback) {
    this.subscribers.pre[event] = this.subscribers.pre[event] || [];
    this.subscribers.pre[event].push(callback);
    
}.bind(PubSub.prototype)

PubSub.prototype.subscribe.post = function(event,callback) {
    this.subscribers.post[event] = this.subscribers.post[event] || [];
    this.subscribers.post[event].push(callback);
}.bind(PubSub.prototype)

PubSub.prototype.publish = function(...params) {
  const keys = ['pre', 'main', 'post']
    for (const k of keys){
    const [event, ...args] = params
    if (this.subscribers[k][event]) {
      const subs = this.subscribers[k][event]
      for (const sub of subs) {
          sub(...args)
      }
    }
  }
}


x = new PubSub();

x.subscribe.post("test", () => {console.log('test post')})
x.subscribe("test", () => {console.log('test sub')})
x.subscribe.pre("test", () => {console.log('test pre')})

x.publish("test") // Triggers pre -> main -> post as expected
x.publish("ing") // Nothing happens because there are no subscribers
```